# Pdfptable getting duplicate table

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation

I think this funny but i dont know where iam stuck.
Iam trying to create a table in PDF document by using itextsharp and successfully its creating the table as you can see the image

[image: Duplicate table]

Below is the code iam using to generate PDF.

```
 private static void TestPDF()
    {
        Document document = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 60, 60, 10, 0);
        try
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@"C:\PdfUpload\" + "testFile" + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 4, 16, 4, 10, 4, 10, 4, 10, 10, 10, 4, 10, 10, 7, 6, 8 });
            table.TotalWidth = 580;
            //table.WidthPercentage = 120;

            PdfPCell cell = null;

            modifycell(cell, "", ref table, 2, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "Formative Asssessment", ref table, 8, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "Summetive Assessment", ref table, 3, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "Final Result", ref table, 3, 0);

            modifycell(cell, "Year", ref table, 0, 2);
            modifycell(cell, "Module Name", ref table, 0, 2);
            modifycell(cell, "Digital Assessment", ref table, 2, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "Group work", ref table, 2, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "Assignment", ref table, 2, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "Subtotal", ref table, 2, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "Examanation", ref table, 3, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "Final (100%)", ref table, 0, 2);
            modifycell(cell, "Symbol", ref table, 0, 2);
            modifycell(cell, "Status (Pass/Fail)", ref table, 0, 2);

            modifycell(cell, "%", ref table, 0, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "Weighted Controbution (20%)", ref table, 0, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "%", ref table, 0, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "Weighted Controbution (10%)", ref table, 0, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "%", ref table, 0, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "Weighted Controbution (30%)", ref table, 0, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "Weighted Controbution (60%)", ref table, 0, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "Subminimum achieved", ref table, 0, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "%", ref table, 0, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "Weighted Controbution (40%)", ref table, 0, 0);
            modifycell(cell, "Subminimum achieved", ref table, 0, 0);
            table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 8, 700, writer.DirectContent);
            document.Add(table);
            document.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception oException) { string sMessage = oException.ToString(); }
    }

    private static void modifycell(PdfPCell cell, string str, ref PdfPTable table, int Colspan = 0, int RowSpan = 0,
        int Width = 0)
    {
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font font = new Font(bf, 6);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(str, font));
        if (RowSpan > 0)
            cell.Rowspan = RowSpan;
        if (Colspan > 0)
            cell.Colspan = Colspan;
        if (Width > 0)
            cell.Width = Width;
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(220, 220, 220);
        cell.Border = 1;
        cell.BorderColorLeft = BaseColor.BLACK;
        cell.BorderWidthLeft = .5f;
        cell.BorderColorRight = BaseColor.BLACK;
        cell.BorderWidthRight = .5f;
        cell.BorderColorBottom = BaseColor.BLACK;
        cell.BorderWidthBottom = .5f;
        table.AddCell(cell);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you add the table twice?

You add it once at absolute positions with this line:

```
table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 8, 700, writer.DirectContent);
```

Then you add it a second time with this line:

```
document.Add(table);
```

It shouldn't surprise you that the table is added twice. Make up your mind, and remove one of those lines.

Comment: Hi @Bruno Lowagie just a week before i have started using iTextSharp and i was bit confused over there, but thank you for the quick reply thats works fine.

Comment: It is custom to accept an answer if it solved your problem. (See the check mark next to the score that is currently 0.)